# Retrieving JSON data is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Below I have a JSON array in my main PHP file. As you can see `$firstname_error` and `$lastname_error` are variables which I intend to pass to AJAX in order to have it displayed in two separate divs. At the moment nothing shows up and am unsure why. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

### PHP & JSON

```
if (empty($_POST["City"])) {
    $city_error = "A city required";
}

if (empty($_POST["E-mail"])) {
    $email_error = "E-mail is required";
}

echo json_encode(array("city" => $city_error, "email" => $email_error));
```

### AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "destination.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.trim() != '') {
                    $('.error4').html(data.city);
                    $('.error5').html(data.email);
                }
            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

`.error4` and `.error5` currently displays nothing.

Comment: If you add some debugging logic to the `error` handler you'll probably get some information to help you find the issue. Alternatively you could check the network tab of the console to find out what the responseText and HTTP status code of the current request is.  Also note that `data` is an object. Calling `trim()` on an object will give you a syntax error

Comment: What is in `data` when it comes back?

Comment: There isn't any error I've checked. I added an alert to success, I confirm that it is submitting.

Comment: Is `data` populated when your success function executes?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I think it is populated.

Comment: I am using jQuery v3.1.1

Comment: You could do a `console.log(data)` as a quick and dirty way to test if it is.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken you should be getting an error because you're calling `trim()` on an object since you have `dataType: 'json',`

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That is the error I think. Do you know how to fix this error? I just started PHP a day ago, sorry if i sound stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have `dataType: 'json',` the data variable passed to your `success` function is going to be an object so you can't use `trim()`.

To check if the value exists in the response you can use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) on `data`:

```
success: function (data) {

    $('.error4').text(data.hasOwnProperty('city') ? data.city : '');
    $('.error5').text(data.hasOwnProperty('email') ? data.email : '');
},
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I believe your `if` condition is not true, So try changing your `success` function like this:

```
success: function (data) {
    if (data.city.trim() != '') {
        $('.error4').html(data.city);
    } 
    if (data.email.trim() != '') {
        $('.error5').html(data.email);
    }
}
```

Comment: as per the code snippet of `Php & Json` he is using `$city_error` or `$email_error` to either blank or error message, So the response will always have these keys `echo json_encode(array("city" => $city_error, "email" => $email_error));` depend upon value can be blank.

Comment: Right you are. Sorry about that!

Comment: It's okay @RossWilson, by the way your answer is more accurate as you are checking for `hasOwnProperty` which is more secure way. Thumbs Up!

Comment: Cheers, Dude!  :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. Use `if(data !== null)` instead of `if (data.trim() != '')`